# Projecting LiDAR data from GCS to state plane coordinate system

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, lidar, las, error-000210

I have LiDAR data that is in GCS NAD83. I have converted that LiDAR data into an LAS Dataset for use in ArcGIS Pro. I'm now trying to convert that LAS dataset into a raster and the tool keeps failing with the the message:

> Error 000210: Cannot create output . Results window below.

[image: LAS Dataset to Raster Results]

[ESRI's documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00201-00225-000210.htm) states that this error results from either a data lock, incorrect path or limited access rights. I know this isn't the case, however. The output directory is on the C drive of my pc. I have also tried exporting to a tif file and gotten the same results. I've come across others that have had this issue and it seems that the problem frequently occurs if the original LiDAR data is in a GCS. Using lastools, I was able to confirm that our data is in NAD83 GCS.

How can I convert that to a projected coordinate system in order to successfully run this tool?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [Extract LAS (3D Analyst)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/extract-las.htm) tool to convert the LAS Dataset to the correct Stateplane:

> Creates new LAS files from point cloud data in a LAS dataset or point
> cloud scene layer.